# How to set swap in /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume if I have two swap partitons?

Tags: 12.04, swap

I have two swap partitions in fstab :

```
    /dev/sda8    none            swap    sw,pri=1           0       0
    /dev/sdb8    none            swap    sw,pri=1           0       0
```

How to set swap in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file?

According to [SwapFaq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) this will not work for 12.04:

> INFO: This will not work for 12.04, resume from hibernate work differently in 12.04.

How to do it in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Really nice introductions exist in the link. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Check UUID

```
 sudo blkid
```

Then

```
 sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

to pull up the boot loader configuration.
Look for the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="" and using your UUID add:

```
resume=UUID=41e86209-3802-424b-9a9d-d7683142dab7
```

That means change this

```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to this

```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=41e86209-3802-424b-9a9d-d7683142dab7"
```

save then edit:

```
gksu gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

and make sure its contents are

```
RESUME=UUID=41e86209-3802-424b-9a9d-d7683142dab7
```

(with your UUID of course in place of mine). Save the file!

```
 sudo update-grub
 sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Reboot!

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Edit: Technically only one of the two methods needs to be used, the kernel parameter in the grub file will take precedence over the initramfs resume config file

Comment: In GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, does 'resume' need to be upcase: 'RESUME'? I find in /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume it is upcase.

Comment: check the link which i have pasted in last ..... its in lowercase ...

Comment: The two swaps form a raid0. If I can choose both of it in /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume ? If I must choose only one of the both?

Comment: i think you need to choose the raid0 uuid

Comment: The two swaps work like raid0, but they are not real raid0. So no raid0 UUID. You can see it on the top of post. I want to know if I must choose only one of /dev/sda8 and /dev/sdb8 in those config file .

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq is not for 12.04. "INFO: This will not work for 12.04, resume from hibernate work differently in 12.04." How to do in 12.04?

Comment: i do not know about that ....if this isn’t helping you then i should delete my answer...

Comment: I don't understand why you update `/etc/default/grub`? At the message is from `initramfs`, changing `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` should be more than enough. You add another dependency in Grub, which will make the next change much more difficult. But thanks for pointing out the `resume` file + `update-initramfs`, that did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

(18.04) You can also edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and change `RESUME=UUID=$uuid` to the output of `blkid /dev/raidN` (whatever block device your 2 swap devices are RAID'd as)